# Should I block access to the Internet Archive crawler? (Archive.org)

Tags: magento-1.9

The internet archive is a fantastic resource, however, my magento shop is scanned by the crawler all the time.

Should I block the crawler?

Very often we don't want the previous products prices available for all time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes if you don't want previous prices to show

No if you ever think you are likely to lose some CMS text based content that you might want to restore

It's ultimately your decision.

You can disallow that in robots.txt

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```